# ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Filter Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code in which i use ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add to import a CSV file. But while importing i need to filter only those rows containing value given by user. Below is the code. I have Highlighted and Bold the portion where i give the filter criteria as **[Object ID] = 140**. But what i want is, instead of  **[Object ID] = 140**, I want **Object ID = xObjID**, where xObjID is input taken from user **xObjID = InputBox(“Enter Object ID”)**. But its not working. Is there any alternative. Please help.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=”S2KVTQ_VTQTimeTable”, Formula:= _

        “let” & Chr(13) & “” & Chr(10) & ”    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(“”” & xFileName & “””),[Delimiter=””,””, Columns=6, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),” & Chr(13) & “” & Chr(10) & ”    #””Changed Type”” = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{“”Column1″”, Int64.Type}, {“”Column2″”, Int64.Type}, {“”Column3″”, type number}, {“”Column4″”, type datetime}, {“”Column5″”, type nu” & _

        “mber}, {“”Column6″”, Int64.Type}}),” & Chr(13) & “” & Chr(10) & ”    #””Removed Other Columns”” = Table.SelectColumns(#””Changed Type””,{“”Column2″”, “”Column3″”, “”Column4″”}),” & Chr(13) & “” & Chr(10) & ”    #””Renamed Columns”” = Table.RenameColumns(#””Removed Other Columns””,{{“”Column2″”, “”Object ID””}, {“”Column3″”, “”Value””}, {“”Column4″”, “”Date & Time””}}),” & Chr(13) & “” & Chr(10) & ”    #””Filtered Rows”” = Table.SelectRows(#””Rename” & _

        “d Columns””, each ([Object ID] = 140))” & Chr(13) & “” & Chr(10) & “in” & Chr(13) & “” & Chr(10) & ”    #””Filtered Rows”””
```

Comment: I don't think the code is working. I pasted the lines in VBA editor, but giving multiple errors. Try to correct the syntax according to your requirement. When it works, try by replacing "= 140)" with " =  " & xObjID & ")"

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working great.